# How Implicit inner join works with multiple WHERE clause conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

With Explicit Inner join, we specify the common column names from both tables and it selects records that have matching values in these columns.

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
WHERE Orders.amount >= 200;
```

But with Implicit Inner join, we just use the WHERE clauses and specify the conditions to be the match. So I want to understand how joining works for multiple conditions, Does the order of conditions matter?

I am asking this because I have two tables like the below:-

**Table1: Customers**

| customer_id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 25 |
| 2 | Marry | 22 |

**Table2: Orders**

| order_id | amount | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 5 |

The `customer_id` field in the `orders` table stores the values of the `customer_id` field of the `customers` table. And unfortunately, we don't have any foreign key constraint on the `customer_id` field of the `orders` table. So if you see the above `orders` table, the **customer_id=5** doesn't exist in the `customers` table and when I run the below query, it returns the below result.

**Query:-**

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
AND Orders.amount >= 200;
```

**Result:-**

| Customers.customer_id | Orders.customer_id | Customers.name | Orders.amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (null) | 5 | (null) | 200 |

All the field's data from the table `Orders` is being fetched and the field's data for the `customers` table is returned as empty data. But ideally inner join only returns the data if there is a match from both tables?

I might be misunderstanding something and clearing my basics.

Thanks for the help!

**Update:**

I really apologize for this but I just noticed in the code there is **(+)** on the right side of the WHERE clause which I was excluded thinking is of no use and now I came to know it denotes RIGHT OUTER join. And now the query results make sense to me.

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id (+)
AND Orders.amount >= 200;
```

Thanks to the StackOverflow community, you are the best!

Comment: Are you sure that this query runs under oracle? it has 2 where clauses. If you run it you get error ora-00933 (at least on the version I have)

Comment: @gsalem, thanks for pointing it out. Updated. I was shortening the query to make it easy to ask here.

Comment: As the implicit join syntax was superseded by the ansi sql join syntax 30+ years ago, I'm not sure why you are bothering with implicit joins as it is not considered good practice? The ansi sql syntax is much easier to read and debug - as your question clearly illustrates

Comment: I understand it @NickW bro, but I just want to understand how it is even returning the record as inner join only returns the data if there is a match from both ends. In our case, `customer_id` is `null` and `5` and they are not _matching_.

Comment: @NickW I keep hearing folks say native Oracle syntax is "not good practice". Why is that? Age cannot be the only reason.

Comment: @Arpit, please double check your data and query, I don't believe what you are describing is really happening.

Comment: @PaulW, SQL developer shows empty values as (null).

Comment: As others have pointed out, your example data and query ***do not*** generate the example results.

Comment: @PaulW as I said in my comment "The ansi sql syntax is much easier to read and debug" - mainly because it separates out the join logic from the filter/where logic and makes it much easier to understand the type of join (LEFT/RIGHT/INNER/OUTER, etc). I think this question makes the reason quite clear: if the questioner had stuck to ansi sql syntax they wouldn't have needed to ask this question as it's obvious how the syntax works

Comment: Well, you are right about LEFT/RIGHT outer joins being clearer, but separating join and filter predicates is actually not always a good idea. Sometimes the line is blurred, and having two different places to see predicates actually can make reading SQL take longer. And for the vast majority of SQL where inner joins predominate, it simply takes  lot less typing to use Oracle's own native syntax. Further, they have always had more bugs in their ANSI implementation (since it isn't their native style but an add-on in order to be industry compliant), and hints often work better with the native.

Comment: So, I think it's really a matter of preference, not a "right" or a "wrong" way.

Comment: While you are obviously free to hold your own opinions, the ANSI SQL standard is the industry standard, has been since at least 1992 and was created because of issues such as the confusing implicit join syntax (feel free to google why the standard was created if you want more background) - so it is the right way as far as the industry is concerned - and therefore is also the right way as far as most employers are concerned (which may, or may not, influence you)

Comment: Sure, but if you're 100% Oracle and no chance of needing portability or working on other RDBMSs, it's a toss-up. Oracle's big enough to do its own thing in addition to giving the nod to industry "standards". Another drawback to ANSI is that it requires you to choose a base table and join tables. For inner joins, there is no conceptual distinction between them, but the ANSI syntax forces you to make one. Also, I've seen numerous cases of developers putting predicates in the wrong place when using ANSI and that can cause performance issues. There are strengths and weaknesses of both styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
AND Orders.amount >= 200;
```

cannot produce the output you showed. This is an inner join, and since there is no matching customer_id = 5 in the customers table, it will not show the order record for customer_id 5 either. If you wanted to see it, you'd need an outer join:

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.customer_id(+) = Orders.customer_id
AND Orders.amount >= 200;
```

To answer your specific question, the order of join clauses does not matter, nor the order of columns in the join clause. Join predicates are treated the same as filter predicates and evaluated in any order Oracle pleases without changing the result. There's something wrong with your test. Please double-verify your SQL and its results.

Comment: SQL developer shows empty values as _(null)_

Comment: Can you double check and reverify your SQL and results?

Answer (score 3):

Your query:

```sql
SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
AND Orders.amount >= 200;
```

Then the legacy comma-join can be replaced with an ANSI-standard `CROSS JOIN` and is the same as:

```sql
SELECT c.customer_id, o.customer_id, c.name, o.amount
FROM   Customers c CROSS JOIN Orders o
WHERE  c.customer_id = o.customer_id
AND    o.amount >= 200;
```

Which, in turn, is the same as:

```sql
SELECT c.customer_id, o.customer_id, c.name, o.amount
FROM   Customers c
       INNER JOIN Orders o
       ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE  o.amount >= 200;
```

Which is the same as your first query.

> Does the order of conditions matter?

No

> when I run the below query, it returns the below result.

That result is impossible as `Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id` is not true in the output so the result cannot be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run your own code ? It doesn't show the results you posted.

```
SQLcl: Release 22.4 Production on Mon Apr 17 15:10:13 2023
koen>CREATE TABLE customers (customer_id,name,age)
  2  AS
  3  (
  4  SELECT 1,  'John', 25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2,  'Marry',    22 FROM DUAL 
  6* );

Table CUSTOMERS created.

koen>CREATE TABLE orders (order_id,amount,customer_id) 
  2  AS
  3  (
  4  SELECT 1,  100,    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2,  200,    5 FROM DUAL
  6* );

Table ORDERS created.
```

Your query - using traditional join syntax.

```
koen>SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
  2  FROM Customers, Orders
  3  WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id(+)
  4* AND Orders.amount >= 200;

no rows selected
```

same query rewritten using ANSI join syntax

```
koen>SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
  2    FROM Customers
  3         JOIN Orders ON Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
  4*   WHERE Orders.amount >= 200;

no rows selected
```

Query rewritten to produce the results you display - using traditional join syntax.

```
koen>SELECT Customers.customer_id, Orders.customer_id, Customers.name, Orders.amount
  2  FROM Customers, Orders
  3  WHERE Customers.customer_id(+) = Orders.customer_id
  4* AND Orders.amount >= 200;

   CUSTOMER_ID    CUSTOMER_ID NAME       AMOUNT 
______________ ______________ _______ _________ 
                            5               200
```

same query rewritten using ANSI join syntax

```
koen>SELECT customers.customer_id, orders.customer_id, customers.name, orders.amount
  2    FROM orders
  3         left outer JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
  4*   WHERE orders.amount >= 200;

   CUSTOMER_ID    CUSTOMER_ID NAME       AMOUNT 
______________ ______________ _______ _________ 
                            5               200
```